# Is http://example/resource# and http://example/resource equivalent?

Tags: http

I've seen many applications substitute "#" when they wish to satisfy href property of the an anchor tag. While I understand how it operates, is it valid to say that urls of the form:

http://somesite.com/resource.html#

and

http://somesite.com/resource.html

are equivalent?  If not, what does an empty value for the # signify? I've most often seen browsers interpret this as "top of page".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hashtag `#` is a client side only fragment identifier. The symbol refers to an identifier inside the content. That content can be either `text/html` or XML.

A URL address like http://somesite.com/resource.html# ends with an empty fragment identifier. Empty fragment identifiers are not technically valid, but are valid URL addresses.

The browser **will not** match `<div id="">....</div>` using an empty fragment.

Instead the browser treats the empty fragment as an invalid identifier. So it is ignored. It does not specify a point to the top of the page. If you open a URL address that ends in a `#` empty fragment, scroll down to the bottom and click *refresh*. The browser will not refresh to the top of the page. It will refresh to the current location.

Fragments can be used in browsers for custom content types. Such as applications or PDF documents.

Comment: What do you mean by "*Empty fragment identifiers are not technically valid*"? According to which specification? [RFC 3986](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3.5) states that the "format and resolution is [...] dependent on the media type", and in the scope of RFC 3986 an empty fragment identifier is perfectly valid.

Comment: @LukasGraf yes, I think we're in agreement but just confused about wording. The RFC states it's a valid URL, but to a web browser it is not a valid identifier. There is no DOM element that will match an empty fragment identifier. Even if you assign one an empty ID. That doesn't mean it's an invalid URL.

Comment: It's not a particularly meaningful identifier - that doesn't mean it's not valid though. From what I can tell from the available specs the behavior is simply undefined in the context of `text/html`.

Answer (score 0):

Summary of info in the [specification for URL parsers](http://url.spec.whatwg.org/#parsing):

The `#` will set the URL's `fragment` to the empty string and essentially tells the parser to expect a fragment string (which may refer to a specific region of the page). If the URL ends at that point, the `fragment` is still the empty string, and the result in the browser should be as if the `#` did not even exist in the URL.

So a trailing `#` doesn't so much specify "top of the page" as it produces what should be the behavior of the browser parsing a URL without the trailing `#`